# Cannot install php-gd php-xml on my VPS

Tags: php, centos

I'm running a centos6 32 bit VPS on Digitalocean. There I want to install php-gd, php-xml according to [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-drupal-on-a-virtual-server-running-centos-6--2)

But I get this error. Not sure why those updated pkgs are not resolved!

```
    #yum install php-mbstring php-gd php-xml
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.trouble-free.net
 * epel: epel.mirror.constant.com
 * extras: mirror.metrocast.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.constant.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-gd.i686 0:5.3.3-23.el6_4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4 for package: php-                                                                                gd-5.3.3-23.el6_4.i686
---> Package php-mbstring.i686 0:5.3.3-23.el6_4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4 for package: php-                                                                                mbstring-5.3.3-23.el6_4.i686
---> Package php-xml.i686 0:5.3.3-23.el6_4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4 for package: php-                                                                                xml-5.3.3-23.el6_4.i686
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-gd-5.3.3-23.el6_4.i686 (updates)
           Requires: php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
           Installed: php-common-5.4.19-1.el6.remi.i686 (@remi)
               php-common(x86-32) = 5.4.19-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.i686 (base)
               php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-22.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.i686 (updates)
               php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
Error: Package: php-xml-5.3.3-23.el6_4.i686 (updates)
           Requires: php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
           Installed: php-common-5.4.19-1.el6.remi.i686 (@remi)
               php-common(x86-32) = 5.4.19-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.i686 (base)
               php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-22.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.i686 (updates)
               php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
Error: Package: php-mbstring-5.3.3-23.el6_4.i686 (updates)
           Requires: php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
           Installed: php-common-5.4.19-1.el6.remi.i686 (@remi)
               php-common(x86-32) = 5.4.19-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.i686 (base)
               php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-22.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.i686 (updates)
               php-common(x86-32) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```